# Making a hexagon from four sided face

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to model this:
[image: Reference image of coffee pot]

The part that is giving me trouble is the small **bolt shaped** safety valve on the bottom section.

It's a **hexagon** so I could model it alone by using a six sided cylinder mesh.
But I have no idea how to implement this with my existing mesh, which is below:
[image]

Comment: It depends on whether you really need that bolt being indented into actual mesh. It might be useful to put that bolt atop of the model. You can also model it of course but I think you should add Subsurf modifier and then just go with intruding this quad inside, it will be rounded with Subsurf. This is one of the ways, without adding extra geometry on your mesh

Answer (score 6):

In your case it really doesn't seem to be necessary to model this all joined together into one continuous mesh, but if you really want to, try erasing two faces instead of just one, it will make topology a lot easier.

Erase two faces from the side of your conical surface, then use the *Bridge Edgeloops* operator to join the two resulting 6 edge loops.

[image]