# maintaining quads when cutting circles into mesh

Tags: modeling

After using either boolean, knife project or something, how can I change the mesh to keep it as clean quads rather than having alot of ngons, which results in terrible geometry after applying a subsurface modifier in high poly models.

Comment: Never use Booleans to begin with, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/making-a-hexagon-from-four-sided-face and use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)

Comment: To cut a circle use the looptools addon like in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45824/arrange-selected-vertices-in-a-circle

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/how-to-make-a-perforated-plate/51243#51243 and: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object/7932#7932